# UserDialogs Loading does not show up

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to see Loading progress as follows, but it does not show up.

**View.cs**

```
ViewModel.SelectedCommand.Execute(null);
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public ICommand SelectedCommand
{
    get
    {
       return new MvxAsyncCommand(async () =>
       {
         // the following does not show loading
          using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Loading..."))
          {
             var task = await _classroomService.GetClassRoomAsync(SelectedClassroom.Id);
             ObservableCollection<ClassroomViewModel> class = new ObservableCollection<ClassroomViewModel>(task.ConvertAll(x => new ClassViewModel(x)));
          }
       });
      }
 }
```

**Another example**

```
public ICommand ReloadCommand
{
    get
    {
      return new MvxAsyncCommand(async () =>
      {
          await RefreshList();
       });
     }
}

// the following also does not show loading
private async Task RefreshList()
{
   using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Loading..."))
   {
       var task = await _classService.GetClasses();
   }
}
```

Comment: where does it not show up? Android? iOS? Have you had a look at the output? Can you post it?

Comment: I am working on Android environment. I cannot able yo see loading dialog

Comment: Try using UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading...") to show it and UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading(); to hide it afterwards

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Acr.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserDialogs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserDialogs/) see that it's depreated and you should use directly [Acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs).

Check if you have correctly initialized it as follows:

You have to register it in App.cs of your PCL project:

`Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IUserDialogs>(() => UserDialogs.Instance);`

And init from the android platform project in your main activity:

`UserDialogs.Init(() => Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity)`

Another thing to take into account is that you should inject it in your constructor as an `IUserDialogs` (you can use the static Instance way but it adds more flexibility and it is more testable by injecting it):

```
private readonly IUserDialogs _dialogs;
public ProgressViewModel(IUserDialogs dialogs)
{
    this._dialogs = dialogs;
}
```

and use it like

```
private async Task RefreshList()
{
   using (this._dialogs.Loading("Loading..."))
   {
       try
       {
           var task = await this._classService.GetClasses();
       }
       catch(Exception exc)
       {
           // This is done only for debugging to check if here lies the problem
           throw exc;
       }
   }
}
```

You can check if it is properly working by calling something like

```
public ICommand MyTestCommand
{
    get
    {
       return new MvxAsyncCommand(async () =>
       {
         // the following should should Loading for 3 seconds
          using (this._dialogs.Loading("Loading..."))
          {
             await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
          }
       });
    }
 }
```

HIH

Comment: Still does not show. I believe it does not like to run in the background thread. I do not know how to handle.

Comment: You can try wrapping it in `this.InvokeOnMainThread(() => {...});`. Does your console shows any output of what might be happening?

Comment: could you please insert into your answer?

Comment: I've thought it twice and it shouldn't be wrapped because you won't be able to await your classService correctly. Furthermore the examples given in https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/master/src/Samples/Samples/ViewModels/ProgressViewModel.cs are all async commands so I don't think that is the problem. Could you please see in your output if you have something that points out to the problem? Also wrap your GetClasses() call in a try catch so you can see if that is breaking and thus finishes the dialog before you can see it

Comment: why did you add `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));`, in the given link, they use it for demo purpose.

Comment: I also added it as demo/test, as you can see it is inside `MyTestCommand`. The `RefreshList` stays as it was wrapped in a try catch to see if you get an exception

Comment: Still did not work. I have added try & catch as well.

Comment: but does it never enter in the catch? And have you checked your output to see if there is some logs in there?

Comment: It never enters to catch

Answer (score 0):

I dont like this approuch but it works

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{

    try
    {
        using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading(("Loading...")))
        {
            await Task.Delay(300);
            await _syncController.SyncData();           
            //Your Service code
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var val = ex.Message;
        UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("Test", val.ToString(), "Ok");
    }
});
```